# How can I order my table's columns using a keyword?

Tags: php, html, twig

My column is currently `{article, formation , tous article , tous formation, notif, offre}`. I want to make it in this order `{article, tous articles , espace&nbsp, formation , tous formation , &nbsp, notif , offre}`

This is my code, the `td` is named: `ban.page`

```
<table id="liste-offresemploi" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="5">#</th>
          <th>Titre 1</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Page</th>
     <th>pagetest</th>
          <th width="20">Statut</th>
          <th>URL</th>
          <th width="5"></th>
          <th width="5" class="header"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% if nb_bannieres > 0 %}

          {% for bann in bannieres %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ bann.idbanniereinterne }}</td>
                <td>{{ bann.titre }}</td>
                <td>{% if bann.type == 2 %} Publicité {% else %} {% if bann.type == 1 %} Structure {% endif %} {% endif %}</td>
                <td id="tri">{{bann.page }}</td>
       <td>{% if bann.page == "articles" %} 0 {% else %} {% if bann.page == "toutarticles" %} 1 {% endif %} {% endif %}  </td>
                <td><a href="#?" class="toogleactif" name="banniereinterne-{{ bann.idbanniereinterne }}" rel="{% if bann.actif %}0{% else %}1{% endif %}">
                         {% if bann.actif %}
                          <button class="btn btn-success actifjs">Actif</button>
                          {% else %}
                          <button class="btn btn-warning actifjs">Non Actif</button>
                          {% endif %}
                          </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ bann.url }}</td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit btnadmin btnedit" title="Editer" rel="table_banniereinterne|id_{{ bann.idbanniereinterne }}"></span></td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btnadmin deladmin" title="Supprimer" rel="{{ bann.idbanniereinterne }}|banniereinterne|0"></span></td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Are you using a template engine? I cannot seem to find any PHP code or SQL queries in your code example. Please provide more context.

Comment: I think what you'e looking for is [usort](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). You can define a comparison function for your `bann` object based on your criteria. Another option is [array_multisort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) but I think the former will be more useful for you.

Comment: @user3070123 Are you in the ability to order the results where you retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to add in your entity a field `order` (type int) and give the order value

```
Category     | Order
------------ | ------
article      | 2
formation    | 3
tous article | 1
```

And then order in your `query` by this `Order` column `ASC` and you will get

```
tous article
article
formation
```